# How to view which query is running on MySQL slave

Tags: mysql, database-replication

Some queries were executed on master database but are taking time in getting replicated to slave database. How do I identify which query of the master is currently being executed by the slave? The query log is not enabled on the master. I have root access to only slave.

Edit 1: On the slave, `binlog_format = ROW`. An update query can run quickly on the master, but if the table is heavy and not-indexed, it may take a long time in getting executed on slave. If I can figure which query is getting executed, I can verify this theory,  analyze the query and index the table.

Edit 2: MySQL Version 5.6.27.
I can run `show slave status`. Hence, I have access to (Relay_Master_Log_File, Exec_Master_Log_Pos) or (Relay_Log_File, Relay_Log_Pos) coordinates. Using 1 of these, is it possible to view which query is currently in execution (or replication)

Comment: First question is: Does it matter? What is your problem behind the question? Does SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; help in this case?

Comment: `show full processlist` just gives that "system user" is either in "Waiting for master to send event" or "System Lock" state. No other query is running on the database but the lag is consistently increasing since last few hours.

Comment: Not sure but maybe these links will help you: 
http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36912/mysql-slaves-lag-behind-master
https://www.percona.com/blog/2014/05/02/how-to-identify-and-cure-mysql-replication-slave-lag/

Comment: Thanks Jorgen. This link seems to mention the same thing which I believe is happening here. I have edited my question to incorporate more information.

Comment: Can slow query log help you to find this query? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/slow-query-log.html 
Good luck!

Comment: By default, a replication slave does not write replicated queries to the slow query log. No luck :-/

Comment: I can run `show slave status`. Hence, I have access to (Relay_Master_Log_File, Exec_Master_Log_Pos) or (Relay_Log_File, Relay_Log_Pos). Using 1 of these, can I not see which query is currently in execution (or replication)

Comment: What version of MySQL? I see in the documentation --log-slow-slave-statements. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options-slave.html never used this myself

Comment: MySQL 5.6.27
Edited in the original post as well.

Comment: try this you can get realtime out put of running queries  http://maxwells-daemon.io/